# Anybody know a simple way to pass checkbox states between pages?

Tags: http, checkbox

I have a collection of checkboxes on a landing page.

Once a user has checked some of them, they proceed to a completely separate html page where those same checkboxes should appear with their selections persisted.

What is the simplest way to achieve this? I'm leaning toward passing the data through the query string but other suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have several possibilities to have a persistence layer in your application.

#### Session:

Probably the safest way is to use a session to store all the user input data given. Note that this is temporary, so at the very end you have to do some kind of save to for example a database.

This is the only option where the user cannot change anything they have provided on their own (and thus maybe break your application)

#### Query String:

As you have mentioned, you could just append the checkboxes which are checked at the query string.

#### POST Parameter

Have some hidden input fields on the following pages and push your values through the various sites via POST values.

#### Cookies/localstorage

If backend is not an option, use Cookies or localstorage.